# RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path error

Tags: java, jax-rs

I have created one endpoint similar to the others that are working without a problem

```
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public interface TransactionsResource {

    @POST
    @Path("/list")
    Response findAllByApprovalDateAndAmount(TransactionsByApprovalDateReqDto request);
}
```

When I am trying to hit this endpoint from Postman the same way I am doing with the already working endpoints I get this error

```
"error": "RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/BackOfficeRestAPI/test/list"
}
```

This path http://localhost:8080/BackOfficeRestAPI/ is working without a problem on the other endpoints, but only here I get error. Even when I move the code to other existing interface it is working. I have tried almost everything - like setting to get/post, renaming Path strings

Comment: 1) Are you using the JPA Entity as the REST endpoint? --- 2) Is this running with RESTeasy or with Spring?

Comment: @Andreas This is running with wildfly. It's JAVA EE

Comment: I think the problem is you're missing access modifier on the "findAllByApprovalDateAndAmount" method as public

Comment: @Harshana I am so stuck in this problem for few hours that I even tried this despite modifier 'public' to be redundant for interfaces

Comment: Is the request match with the TransactionsByApprovalDateReqDto class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem .... It was configuration problem. All resources are added into one configuration class

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class BackOfficeApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> restResources = new HashSet<>();
        restResources.add(EmailResourceService.class);
        restResources.add(SmsResourceService.class);
```